# MRTK Button press not triggering correctly on Android despite doing so in the Unity Editor

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I am developing an MRTK app for Hololens and mobile platforms and I am using the default MRTK buttons with scripts assigned to them.

In-Editor (when using the hand interaction simulation tool) the buttons work as intended (instanciating a 3d model on press, either with finger touching or left mouse click while the button is centered).

When testing the buttons on my mobile phone on Android, tapping the buttons triggers the sound of being pressed, but nothing happens. I use the DefaultHololens2InputSystemProfile in the MRTK.

Things I checked:

- Button Events triggering correct in the Editor

Things I don't know how to check:

- EventConsole/Some kind of output on Android to check if the Assets or the Buttons are the problem

Any ideas of what I can try?

Comment: This might not be MRTK related answer, but if you controls you are using are on the World space `Canvas`, please make sure that this `Canvas.worldCamera` property has your current camera. Otherwise touch input and/or VR input might not work correctly. While mouse input works fine (Editor and PC build).

Comment: I guess on a mobile phone you wouldn't use the `DefaultHololens2InputSystemProfile` .. on a mobile phone you don't have Articulated hands nor a default Head cursor ... Have you read [this](https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/version/releases/2.2.0/Documentation/CrossPlatform/UsingARFoundation.html)?

Comment: I have used this guideline to create my project build settings for Android. The thing throwing me off is that when I tap on the buttons while being on Android I hear the tap sound and I can see the button doing the "clicked" animation where it contracts. The only thing that does not seem to be triggered is the logic behind it

Answer (score 0):

You got to use the Onclick() event instead of the ButtonPressed, -Released etc. events you usually use for clicking in AR. You should find it right below the ButtonReleased event.